# Created TabBar Programmatically and implemented reside menu but its not working

Tags: ios

I have created tabBar controller programmatically and i have to add Reside menu..i implemented  reside menu and done all process but its not working.

Here is my code:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.tabBarController =[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[LeftMenuView alloc] init]];
    LeftMenuView *leftMenuViewController = [[LeftMenuView alloc] init];

    RESideMenu *sideMenuViewController=[[RESideMenu alloc]initWithContentViewController:navigationController leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController rightMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController];



    sideMenuViewController.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
    sideMenuViewController.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = 1; // UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
    sideMenuViewController.delegate = self;
    sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowOpacity = 0.6;
    sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowRadius = 12;
    sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowEnabled = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = sideMenuViewController;



    //Initialize View controller and speciality

    UIViewController *viewcontroller1=[[HomeView alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller2=[[Speciality alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller3=[[Activity alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller4 =[[Notification alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller5 =[[Profile alloc]init];
  UIViewController *viewconroller6=[[LeftMenuView alloc]init];






    [navigationController pushViewController:viewconroller6 animated:YES];


    self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewcontroller1,viewcontroller2,viewcontroller3,viewcontroller4,viewcontroller5, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController =self.tabBarController;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.376 green:0.729 blue:0.318 alpha:1.000];


    self.window.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

//HomeView.h

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self=[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self){

        UIView *singleView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

        self.title=@"Home";


        self.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];

        UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 50)];

        [navbar setTranslucent:YES];
        [navbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.376 green:0.729 blue:0.318 alpha:1.000]];
        [singleView addSubview:navbar];




        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(presentLeftMenuViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn setTitle:@"Menu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(20, 25, 40, 40);
        [singleView addSubview:btn];


        [self.view addSubview:singleView];

    }
    return self;

}
```

Comment: this https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu   right?

Comment: let me check a couple o'things and ill see what i can find

Comment: actually, nevermind, i see what you did there, one se

Comment: it would be easier if you explaiend what you want your heirarchy to look like when it's done, like do you want the tabBar to show over everytyhing else? and have the menu side items show up as separate from the tabbar as in you have an icon that you press and the side menus pop up out and push the tabbar to the side?

Comment: i need side menu to pop up and push the tab bar to the side

Comment: Okay, so I dont have time to post a whole solution right now, but I'll tell you where your problems are: this     "[navigationController pushViewController:viewconroller6 animated:YES];" isn't going to do anything, since this navigationcontroller wasnt' added to the view heirarchy at all.

Comment: this is the root of ONE of your problems, the next problem is that if you add the tabBar to the rootViewController of the main window, then you won't be able to add another rootviewController unless you first pop this controller off the stack

Comment: if you want to make this work then the suggestion I have is to make the     "navigationController" the ROOTVIEWCONTROLLER of the window, and then within the left side item menu, you place the tabbar controller and then hopefully it will let you place a tabbar in there, but I don't think it will, so you are adding two navigation systems in one and this is very comlicated to do.

Comment: the only problem with this again is that it may not be possible to place the main view controller of the menu slider as a UITabbarController

Comment: also, I just noticed that you tried to place the rootviewcontroller another time, "    self.window.rootViewController = sideMenuViewController;", this will be called first, but the you call to the rootviewcontroller again and try to put in a another rootiveiwcontroller, which is another reason this breaks on you

Comment: So my mistake on AppDelegate.m right?

Comment: in the AppDelegate.m, I'm not sure about the AppDelegate.h

Comment: I see what you are tryign to do and I have a solution in my brain, but just not sure it will work in code

Comment: ok no problem..if u got any idea please let me know

Comment: I will, I have a solution, I think, I've gotta sleep for a bit, but I'll try to post something in a few hours. you have a very good start, and I know what you are tryign to do, just need a few things fixed is all